# .NET WPF. OxyPlot TimeFormat

Tags: string-formatting, time-format, oxyplot

I need to display time in format "HH:mm:ss" in the window.

```
            Plot = new PlotModel();
            Plot.TextColor = OxyColors.Black;

            Plot.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Left, 0, 100));
            Plot.Axes.Add(new DateTimeAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom)
            {
                //StringFormat = "h:mm",
                IsZoomEnabled = false,
                IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds,
                IntervalLength = 80
            });
```

But it doesn't work.

I want to see this result in DateTimeAxis: 0:00:01 - 0:00:05 - 0:00:10 etc.
Help me, please.

[image]

https://github.com/oxyplot

```
    private double _xAxisCounter;

    private void UpdateChart(int mixerNumber)
    {
        DetailsPlot details = _mixerDetailsPlots[mixerNumber];
        UpdateChart(details.LineOfCurrent, details.Mixer.Current.Value);
        UpdateChart(details.LineOfMaximumCurrent, details.Mixer.MaximumCurrent);
    }

    private void UpdateChart(LineSeries line, double value)
    {
        if (line.Points.Count > 500)
        {
            line.Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        line.Points.Add(new DataPoint(_xAxisCounter, value));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you're after something like this:

```
var BottomAxis = new DateTimeAxis();
BottomAxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
BottomAxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot;
BottomAxis.LabelFormatter = d => { return DateTimeAxis.ToDateTime(d).ToString("HH:mm:ss\nyy/MM/dd"); };
myPlotModel.Axes.Add(BottomAxis);
```

All I've done is added a format to the DateTime axis.
In your case you won't need the date part of the format.

Hope this helps!